# Reverse voltage protection circuit operation

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, resistors, diodes

I have this reverse voltage protection circuit:

[image]

Can someone tell me how this circuit protects from very high reverse voltages? I am not able to understand  how the capacitor is connected in such a reverse way and how can it protect the downstream circuit.

Comment: Where’s the rest of the circuit? We need some more context.

Comment: Showing 0 / 15 / ground is confusing. What is the relationship of 0V and ground. || If 15 is negative relative to ground D100 conducts, C1348 is correctly biased abd the resistors dissipate energy.